# Oracle Apex - how to remove region "borders"

Tags: oracle-apex

In my IG I set never stretch column attribute for each column and column span as 9, with that settings I have unnecessary lines/borders. How to remove that lines from IG?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You have used the noStretch property for the IG columns.
  So, this is the
  expected behaviour.
- By default, the width of the IG will extend    itself to fit the
  whole screen. So I recommend you to reduce the    width of the
  Interactive grid.

You can follow any one of the below ways to achieve this

1. You can reduce the column span of the IG.

[image]

2. Below is the second approach.

- Provide a Static ID for the IG. In my case I have provided the Static
  ID as EMP.
- Go to the **Page -> Inline -> CSS** section and paste the below
  code (code to adjust the width of the IG).

```
#EMP {
   width: 50%;
}
```

**Note:** In the above CSS, the 50% can be reduced/increased based on the requirement.